# UdpClient wont connect to IpAdress.Any

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm trying to listen for UDP packets from unknown source. But can't bind on the "unspecified adress" (0.0.0.0 or ::)

I've already tried listening on ::1. But from what i tested that only works for local connections that don't pass the network interface.

```cs
        public async void AwaitDiscoveryReply()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))
                {
                    client.Connect(IPAddress.IPv6Any,4568);

                        var result = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Received DR");
                        var stateProtocol = StateProtocol.FromBytes(result.Buffer);
                        var robeatsDevice = new RobeatsDevice
                        {
                            Id = stateProtocol.DeviceId,
                            Name = stateProtocol.DeviceName,
                            EndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint,
                            StateProtocol = stateProtocol

                        };
                        OnDiscoveryReply(new DeviceDiscoveryEventArgs {RobeatsDevice = robeatsDevice});

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

This keeps throwing the exception: `The requested address is not valid in its context [::]:4568`

Comment: Are you using IPV4 or IPV6?

Comment: IPV6 but i dont think that really matters in this case

Comment: Then the port is already in use.  Try using from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to see what ports are being used.

Comment: jdweng - If the address was already bound the error message would indicate that clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP sockets are connectionless. "Connect" methods on UDP socket implementations, by convention (don't ask me why) establish default endpoints / filter traffic. If you want to receive traffic from any address, you don't need to "connect" at all. Use the constructor with signature UdpClient(Int32, AddressFamily) and delete the Connect() invocation:

```
public async void AwaitDiscoveryReply()
      {
          try
        {
            using (var client = new UdpClient(4568,AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))
            {

                    var result = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Received DR");
                    var stateProtocol = StateProtocol.FromBytes(result.Buffer);
                    var robeatsDevice = new RobeatsDevice
                    {
                        Id = stateProtocol.DeviceId,
                        Name = stateProtocol.DeviceName,
                        EndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint,
                        StateProtocol = stateProtocol

                    };
                    OnDiscoveryReply(new DeviceDiscoveryEventArgs {RobeatsDevice = robeatsDevice});

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: (i'd suggest using `Receive()` and not `ReceiveAsync()` for clarity, by the way...)

Comment: Why's that? Because of the await?

Comment: also this gives me a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied`

Comment: I'm assuming the latter was thrown from under your `OnDiscoveryReply()`, which you don't show.   As the error messages indicates, you must specify the address when sending data - again because UDP is connectionless.  We only see your receive here.

Comment: `Receive()` for blocking-mode sockets (the default, which you are using).   `ReceiveAsync()` for the general case.  It will work as is, but always does the same as Receive(), returning false.

Comment: (If you /do/ `Connect()`, then you don't have to specify an address on send; it uses the "connected" address.  Annoyingly, .NET will throw an exception if you "connect" and send to a different address then the one you "connected" to; most other datagram socket interfaces I've seen allow that flexibility)